# How to convert an audio file (.wav) to ByteBuffer (Android App)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Assume I have an audio file (.wav) like this:

https://storage.googleapis.com/audioset/yamalyzer/audio/cough.wav

I am still looking for a way to convert this audio file to ByteBuffer to pass it to the YAMNET TensorFlow lite model (.tflite) for sound classification (This model return the category that the audio file belong to like speech, typing, music, cough and so on)

https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/yamnet/classification/tflite/1

```
val model = YamnetClassification.newInstance(this)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val audioClip = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(15600), DataType.FLOAT32)
audioClip.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(audioClip)
val scores = outputs.scoresAsTensorBuffer
```

My question: how to convert the audio clip to ByteBuffer to pass it to this function:

```
audioClip.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot convert a file to a buffer. What you can do is put a file in a buffer.

Comment: If I read an audio file like this: val source_file =File("sample.wav").   How to put it in a byte buffer?

Comment: That does not 'read'  a file. And the File class needs a full path. Not only a file name. And why didnt you edit your post? Its still full of conversions.